# How to write (half)-open intervals?

Tags: notation, interval-arithmetic

In [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74994244), the author writes about the interval `(26,100]`. I believe he means that 100 is included while 26 is excluded.

In my country (I'm from Belgium), this is written as `]26,100]`.

Is there a standard notation for (half)-open intervals and if yes, which one is it?

Comment: Both [notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Including_or_excluding_endpoints) are acceptable

Comment: I see $(26,100]$ notation far more often, both on this site and in textbooks, fwiw

Comment: The $(26,100]$ notation is more common in Anglophone countries, whereas the $]26, 100]$ notation, pioneered by Bourbaki, is more common in Francophone countries, and other countries influenced by Bourbaki, like the former Soviet Union. Both notations are described as acceptable by the ISO (in ISO 31-11, later ISO 80000-2:2019) if that's your jam. Basically, up to you. I like the Bourbaki notation, as it distinguishes open intervals from ordered pairs, but that's entirely personal preference.